# Is it possible to create 2 windows each on its own monitor with different bypass compositor value?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 using X with Nvidia graphics card.
There are 2 different resolution monitors connected to the system and configured in extended mode.
I am using GLFW to create a full screen window on the primary monitor and a none full screen window on the second monitor.
GLFW sets the Bypass compositor to on in case of full screen.
It appears (latency is increased on primary) that in the above configuration the compositor ignores this request and is used to handle the full screen window as well.

**Is there a way to check if the compositor is managing a window?

Is the above configuration of 1 window managed by the compositor while the other is not valid?**

Comment: There seem to be no way to check if the bypass compositor is actually in effect (other then seeing screen tear).

Comment: Mutter will bypass compositor for a full screen window which spans over all connected monitors on a given x-screen